# Windows 7 - remove user's profile after logout

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-profile

is it possible to force Windows 7 to remove user's profile after logout?
Computer is being used by many students in library. It won't be in domain.

Answer (score 1):

Create a scheduled task to run DelProf2.exe every five minutes using the command: `delprof2.exe /u`

https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/

Comment: Thanks Greg! That tool may actually also be suitable for other (unrelated) scenario that my current solution solves only partially.

Answer (score 0):

All users added to group *Guests* will work that way by default.

> [Profiles for Members of Guests Group Are Deleted](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/165398/profiles-for-members-of-guests-group-are-deleted)
>
> If a user is added to the *Guests* group (or the *Domain Guests* group,
>   which belongs to the *Guests* group), when the user logs on, that user's
>   profile information is only stored temporarily. When that user logs
>   off, the entire profile is deleted. This includes everything stored in
>   the `%userprofile%` directory: the user's registry hive information,
>   custom desktop icons, and so on.

This is by design and you won't need any tricks.

Comment: I created new profile and added it to Guests group, then I loged in and I changed wallpaper and created few files on Desktop. After logout and login I still see my wallpaper and my files. What went wrong? :)

Comment: And the account isn't a member of Administrators at the same time?

Comment: No, this account is only a member of Guests group

Comment: Give it another try. Log in after adding the user to that group as the group membership takes place during the logon. I've done this several times and it has always worked for me.

Comment: I've tried it using VirtualBox and then on my laptop - it doesn't work.

Comment: GPO can be used, you can set to delete user profiles older than a specified number of days, but restart is required.